# Math.random in a Functions parameters where the function is held within a variable - answer always the same

Tags: javascript

First of all forgive me for the rather confusing title, I have been struggling to figure out how to word my problem correctly.

I have been working on a text based browser game in JS and have created a few 'classes' (Player, Skill, Item, Spell, Enemy). I have created a heal function that can be reused for healing skills, spells or items.

I then store the function in a variable within the objects as follows (comments are added to help you follow):

```
// Skill: name, description, effect
// heal(amt, cost) <-- amount of HP to heal, cost in MP or Stamina
var healingWind = new Skill('Healing Wind', 'A gust of wind that refreshes the 
user.', heal(15, 10));
```

My heal function works great and healingWind.effect() works exactly how it should. What I am trying to do now is to get the ability to heal 15 HP + a random amount based on the players stats (defined in our Player class).

I have tried doing this:

```
// player is an instance of our Player class
var healingWind = new Skill('Healing Wind', 'A gust of wind that refreshes 
the user.', heal(15 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (player.agility * 2)), 10));
```

Everything works how I would expect it although every time the skill is used, the amount remains exactly the same. I then tried to create a function that returns Math.random() and used this in place of Math.random() in the code above, the results were the same.

I then tried to have my random function return a function that returns Math.random() and the results of this were NaN.

I am not sure what I am missing here and have been trying to solve this by myself for quite some time as well as numerous Google searches to no avail. I am not sure whether or not I have explained myself well enough but I hope that you can understand what I am getting at. If anyone needs any further information please let me know and I will try to be as descriptive as possible.

EDIT:

The heal() function - when healingWind.effect() is used players HP is increased by amt and players Stamina is decreased by cost.

```
function heal(amt, cost){
  return function(){
    if(this.constructor.name == 'Item'){
      game.innerHTML += '<br>Using ' + this.name + '!';
      player.currentHp += amt;
    } else if(this.constructor.name == 'Spell'){
      if(player.currentMp >= cost){
        game.innerHTML += '<br>Casting ' + this.name + '!';
        player.currentHp += amt;
        player.currentMp -= cost;
      } else {
        game.innerHTML += '<br>You don\'t have enough Mana to cast this!';
      }
    } else if(this.constructor.name == 'Skill'){
      if(player.currentStamina >= cost){
        game.innerHTML += '<br>Using skill - ' + this.name + '!<br>Healed ' + amt + ' HP!';
    player.currentHp += amt;
    player.currentStamina -= cost;
  } else {
    game.innerHTML += '<br>You don\'t have enough Stamina to use this ability!';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please note - logic for if(currentHP >= maxHp) hasn't been implemented into this function yet but I will get round to that.

--SOLVED--: This is my new code for the heal() function should anyone be interested or find it useful if attempting something similar.

```
function heal(base_amt, cost, attribute, multiply){
  return function(){
    var amt = base_amt;
    if(attribute === 'AGI'){
      amt = Math.floor(amt +(Math.random() * (player.agility * multiply)));
    } else if(attribute === 'STR'){
      amt = Math.floor(amt + (Math.random() * (player.strength * multiply)));
    } else if(attribute === 'END'){
      amt = Math.floor(amt + (Math.random() * (player.endurance * multiply)));
    } else if(attribute === 'INT'){
      amt = Math.floor(amt + (Math.random() * (player.intellect * multiply)));
    } else if(attribute === 'WIL'){
      amt = Math.floor(amt + (Math.random() * (player.willpower * multiply)));
    }

    if(this.constructor.name == 'Item'){
      game.innerHTML += '<br>Using ' + this.name + '!';
      player.currentHp += amt;
      if(player.currentHp >= player.maxHp){
        player.currentHp = player.maxHp;
      }
    } else if(this.constructor.name == 'Spell'){
      if(player.currentMp >= cost){
        game.innerHTML += '<br>Casting ' + this.name + '!';
        player.currentHp += amt;
        player.currentMp -= cost;
        if(player.currentHp >= player.maxHp){
          player.currentHp = player.maxHp;
        }
      } else {
        game.innerHTML += '<br>You don\'t have enough Mana to cast this!';
      }
    } else if(this.constructor.name == 'Skill'){
      if(player.currentStamina >= cost){
        game.innerHTML += '<br>Using ' + this.name + '!<br>Healed ' + amt + ' HP!';
        player.currentHp += amt;
        player.currentStamina -= cost;
        if(player.currentHp >= player.maxHp){
          player.currentHp = player.maxHp;
        }
      } else {
        game.innerHTML += '<br>You don\'t have enough Stamina to use this ability!';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Variables:

```
// All of these work :D note the extra params of the Skill.
var cure = new Spell('Cure', 'Heals a small amount of HP.', heal(40, 15), 'Restoration');
var healingWind = new Skill('Healing Wind', 'A gust of wind that refreshes the user.', heal(15, 11, 'AGI', 2));
var weakPotion = new Item('Weak Healing Potion', 'A weak healing potion.', 5, heal(20));
```

Comment: What does `heal(amt, cost)` return?

Comment: Hi Manuel, I have amended my opening post with the heal function.

Comment: You need to call `Math.random` every time you use the value (which you unfortunately haven't shown us yet)

Comment: `every time the skill is used, the amount remains exactly the same` - where do you expect it to change? or are you saying every time you create a new Skill object the value of the third argument is exactly the same for each instance?

Comment: well, function heal creates a closure where `amt` never changes, so the random value at the time of skill instantiation will never change

Comment: You will have to randomize the `amt` inside the returned function of `heal()`

Comment: What @Phil is getting at is along the correct lines - basically I would like a new random number to be determined each time the effect is called. I understand that I am creating the random number at creation time, I am not sure how to get it to do as I would like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *Jaromanda X* already said, the heal function creates a closure where `amt` never changes. So you must randomize the `amt` inside that closure.

```
function heal(base_amt, cost){
  return function(){
    var amt = base_amt + Math.floor(Math.random() * (player.agility * 2))

    [...]

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this I thought about doing this but I have other abilities that will rely on other character traits (not just agility). Looks like I need a big rethink about how to tackle all the various skills.

Comment: @D.Winning Maybe create a class for that, which will return the randomized boni based on the character traits.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Manuel Otto I have now got my function to do what I would like it to do and edited my original post should anyone need it for reference in future. There are probably much better ways of doing this but as of now it works great :)